# Bloomberg python API (blpapi) installation error

Tags: python, bloomberg, blpapi

I would like to use Bloomberg desktop API for Python.
To do this I have to install package `blpapi`.

My Bloomberg terminal PC environment :

1. WIN10(64bit)
2. Ananconda 4.13.0 and Python 3.9.12
3. No internet environment

Due to no internet environment, I could not use `pip install` option.

Instead I received installation files and tried to install `python setup.py install`

However I enconter error and belows. How to handle it?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bok\Downloads\blpapi-3.18.3\setup.py", line 49, in <module>
    assert blpapiRoot or (blpapiIncludesVar and blpapiLibVar), (
AssertionError: BLPAPI_ROOT (or BLPAPI_INCDIR/BLPAPI_LIBDIR) environment variable isn't defined
```

Comment: Read the [docs](https://github.com/msitt/blpapi-python): *"Set the BLPAPI_ROOT environment variable to the location at which the Bloomberg C++ SDK is installed.*"

Comment: I'm curious as to what you plan to do with the module with no internet connection. That is kind of the whole point, isn't it?